# Angular-Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IQuest[]'

Tags: angular5, angular2-observables

This is my service:

```
getAll<T>():Observable<T> {
   return this.http.get<T>(this.url);
}
```

This is my interface:

```
interface IQuest {
   id:number;
   qn:string;
   imagename:string;
   Option:string[];
   answer:number;
}
```

My component:

```
questions:IQuest[]=[];

ngOnInit(){
 this.service.getAll().subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data);
    this.questions = data;
   },error=>{
     console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Here I am getting an error like

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IQuest[]'. Property
>   'includes' is missing in type '{}'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might wanna use something like this instead:

```
questions: IQuest[] = [] as IQuest[];
```

The other problem is, that the data what you get from your service via http call, is not compatible with the interface that you define.

What can you see in the console at the `console.log(data)` part?

Maybe try to modify to something like this:

```
..
 getAll<T>(): Observable<IQuest> {
..
 this.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.questions.push(data); // or
      this.questions = data;     // if it is an array
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
});
```